# Unsure what is causing this error? Tensorflow? Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Unsure what exactly is causing this error and need help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoAFW.jpg)

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post all code and error messages as plain text.